# Cannot create trigger in mysql at phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create an ID by combining fields after a row has been inserted into the database in phpmyadmin. I get an error on line 3 of the following trigger statement:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `scanID2`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `scanID2` 
AFTER INSERT ON db_name.`scan_data` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE db_name.scan_data 
SET @data1 = concat(RIGHT(scanContent,2), RIGHT(operatorID,2), RIGHT(deviceID,2), RIGHT (scanDate, '-', ''), REPLACE (scanTime, ':', ''));
INSERT INTO db_name.scan_data(scanID) VALUES (@data1);
END
//
```

The error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `scanID2`
AFTER INSERT ON db_name' at line 2
```

OK, so I figured how to get the query executed. The trigger has been created but I don't think it does what it's supposed to do. The records don't get updated. Here's the new code:

```
BEGIN 
SET @data1 = concat(RIGHT(scanContent,2), RIGHT(operatorID,2), RIGHT(deviceID,2), REPLACE (scanDate, '-', ''), REPLACE (scanTime, ':', ''));
INSERT INTO vacseen1_connect.scan_data(scanID) VALUES (@data1);
END
```

Comment: What is the error message ?  Also provide the full trigger statement

Comment: you still need to terminate statements inside the trigger, ie, with semicolons. and i'm not sure what you're trying to do with the update statement. what sort of trigger is it?

Comment: I want the 'scanID' to a combination of digits from scanContent, operatorID, deviceID, scanDate, and scanTime. I'm fetching these details from an android device and inserting a blank '' in the scanID column with these details. After inserting, I want the table to be updated with the trigger for the newly created row.

Comment: Requesting your inputs MySQL_Rockstar and pale_. Have been struggling with this for two days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to consider:

1. Use `BEFORE` event for the trigger instead of `AFTER`. This way you can set the value of `scanID` the same time a row is being inserted.
2. Use `NEW` keyword to access fields of a row being inserted.
3. Since it's one statement trigger now you don't need to change delimiter and use `BEGIN ... END` block.
4. You most likely meant to use `REPLACE` for scanDate.

Try

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER scanID2 
BEFORE INSERT ON scan_data 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.scanID = CONCAT(
    RIGHT(NEW.scanContent, 2), 
    RIGHT(NEW.operatorID, 2), 
    RIGHT(NEW.deviceID, 2), 
    REPLACE(NEW.scanDate, '-', ''), 
    REPLACE (NEW.scanTime, ':', '')
);
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c550/1)** demo